# Cakephp2.3: Custom route does not working

Tags: php, cakephp, routes

I have define the custom route rule as:

```
Router::connect('/permission/', 
                array(
                    'plugin'        => 'Authorization', 
                    'controller'    => 'permissions', 
                    'action'        => 'index',
                    'admin'         => true,
                ),
);
```

With this setting routes works fine for url like http://example.com/permission

But I also need to define route for the parameters

I have tried for it as:

> ```
> Router::connect('/permission/:index', 
>               array(
>                   'plugin'        => 'Authorization', 
>                   'controller'    => 'permissions', 
>                   'action'        => 'index',
>                   'admin'         => true,
>               ),
>               array(
>                   'pass'          => array('index')
>               )
> );
> ```

With this route cake throw exception:

**Error: PermissionController could not be found.**

I want route to be work for

http://example.com/permission/2

It should point to **http://example.com/admin/authorization/permissions/index/2**

can anyone know, how to define custom routes with parameters correct way?

Comment: at where you want  http://example.com/permission/2 to point to ?

Comment: It should point to **http://example.com/admin/authorization/permissions/index/2**

Comment: Could you post the whole routes.php file, at least whatever is written before the `'/permission/:index'` line cuz this seems fine. It might something with a different router connect pattern

Comment: I have been adding this route in plugin routes.php file. So my route file content only line which I have added in question

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your route like as

```
Router::connect('/permission/:id', array('plugin'=>'authorization,'controller' => 'permissions', 'action' => 'index'),array('pass'=>array('id')));
```